# Is it possible to build a ssas cube from view?

Tags: sql, view, ssas, cube

I have try to use visual studio to import table to Data Source View but i cannot find my view in the Data Source View. Try to google but can't find the answer.

Comment: Are you using tabular or Olap cube ?
And can you add print screen to let us know where are you looking for this table in Visual studio

Comment: It is a Olap cube, and i am trying to pull the view from Data Source View - Add/remove tables in visual studio.

Comment: Sorry, i think is it using new named query to add?

Comment: Yes you just have to add the table when you select a table you can import a table or a view